How to click an input with type search using DrissionPage
I am using DrissionPage, similar to Selenium. I want to click on input with type "search". When I am in the page its typing only when I click the input manually. I am using python.
I tried with .click(), .execute_script("arguments[0].focus();", input_element) - this is for Selenium but i didn't find the one for DrissonPage.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Since they don't have real docs you're going to need to look at the code to learn how it works, if you wish to use the package: https://github.com/g1879/DrissionPage/tree/master/DrissionPage

This question is kinda vague. So I am gonna assume you are trying to send an input to a type=search. Here is how you can do it
inputting = driver.ele('@type=search')
inputting.input("Type something here")

If this is not what you want, please add a comment under this post so i can edit it.
https://drissionpage.cn/ (their documentation, i personally use google translate)
